# Not submit any value if checkbox is empty

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this select option. It is always submitting first option value if all checkbox are left unchecked. I want that if non of the checkbox is selected it should not submit any value.

By leaving it empty I am going to get all the records but I will do that from backend.

The snippet is from internet if you have any got solution that will be good also

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test").CreateMultiCheckBox({
    width: '100%',
    defaultText: 'Select Tags',
    height: '250px'
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBox", function() {
    var detail = $(this).next();
    detail.show();
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader input", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var hc = $(this).prop("checked");
    $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").find(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input").prop("checked", hc);
    $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").next().UpdateSelect();
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader", function(e) {
    var inp = $(this).find("input");
    var chk = inp.prop("checked");
    inp.prop("checked", !chk);
    $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").find(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input").prop("checked", !chk);
    $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").next().UpdateSelect();
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBoxDetail .cont input", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").next().UpdateSelect();

    var val = ($(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input:checked").length == $(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input").length)
    $(".MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader input").prop("checked", val);
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBoxDetail .cont", function(e) {
    var inp = $(this).find("input");
    var chk = inp.prop("checked");
    inp.prop("checked", !chk);

    var multiCheckBoxDetail = $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail");
    var multiCheckBoxDetailBody = $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody");
    multiCheckBoxDetail.next().UpdateSelect();

    var val = ($(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input:checked").length == $(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input").length)
    $(".MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader input").prop("checked", val);
  });

  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    var container = $(".MultiCheckBoxDetail");
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      container.hide();
    }
  });
});

var defaultMultiCheckBoxOption = {
  width: '220px',
  defaultText: 'Select Below',
  height: '200px'
};

jQuery.fn.extend({
  CreateMultiCheckBox: function(options) {

    var localOption = {};
    localOption.width = (options != null && options.width != null && options.width != undefined) ? options.width : defaultMultiCheckBoxOption.width;
    localOption.defaultText = (options != null && options.defaultText != null && options.defaultText != undefined) ? options.defaultText : defaultMultiCheckBoxOption.defaultText;
    localOption.height = (options != null && options.height != null && options.height != undefined) ? options.height : defaultMultiCheckBoxOption.height;

    this.hide();
    this.attr("multiple", "multiple");
    var divSel = $("<div class='MultiCheckBox'>" + localOption.defaultText + "<span class='k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down'><svg aria-hidden='true' focusable='false' data-prefix='fas' data-icon='sort-down' role='img' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 320 512' class='svg-inline--fa fa-sort-down fa-w-10 fa-2x'><path fill='currentColor' d='M41 288h238c21.4 0 32.1 25.9 17 41L177 448c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0L24 329c-15.1-15.1-4.4-41 17-41z' class=''></path></svg></span></div>").insertBefore(this);
    divSel.css({
      "width": localOption.width
    });

    var detail = $("<div class='MultiCheckBoxDetail'><div class='MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader'><input type='checkbox' class='mulinput' value='-1982' /><div>Select All</div></div><div class='MultiCheckBoxDetailBody'></div></div>").insertAfter(divSel);
    detail.css({
      "width": parseInt(options.width) + 10,
      "max-height": localOption.height
    });
    var multiCheckBoxDetailBody = detail.find(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody");

    this.find("option").each(function() {
      var val = $(this).attr("value");

      if (val == undefined)
        val = '';

      multiCheckBoxDetailBody.append("<div class='cont'><div><input type='checkbox' class='mulinput' value='" + val + "' /></div><div>" + $(this).text() + "</div></div>");
    });

    multiCheckBoxDetailBody.css("max-height", (parseInt($(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").css("max-height")) - 28) + "px");
  },
  UpdateSelect: function() {
    var arr = [];

    this.prev().find(".mulinput:checked").each(function() {
      arr.push($(this).val());
    });

    this.val(arr);
  },
});
```

```css
.MultiCheckBox {
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.MultiCheckBox .k-icon {
  font-size: 15px;
  float: right;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-top: -7px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 14px;
  color: #787878;
}

.MultiCheckBoxDetail {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.MultiCheckBoxDetailBody {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: white;
}

.MultiCheckBoxDetail .cont {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 2px;
}

.MultiCheckBoxDetail .cont:hover {
  background-color: #cfcfcf;
}

.MultiCheckBoxDetailBody>div>div {
  float: left;
}

.MultiCheckBoxDetail>div>div:nth-child(1) {}

.MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 28px;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
}

.MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader>input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 3px;
}

.MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 24px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col">
    <select name="tag[]" class="form-control" id="test">
      <option value="1">Full Day</option>
      <option value="2">Half Day</option>
      <option value="3">Weekends</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My Result**
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validating a form - if fields are empty add class to each empty one and then don't submit. Stuck on combining into a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55435862/validating-a-form-if-fields-are-empty-add-class-to-each-empty-one-and-then-don)

Comment: @Kinglish No, I want that the form still submits when the checkbox is unchecked but it should now pass any value, because currently it passes first option's value when left unchecked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a widget.

The widget is interfering with the normal passing of form element values.

I solved it by adding an empty value to the original select after creating the multiple option

```js
$(function() {
  $("#test").CreateMultiCheckBox({
    width: '100%',
    defaultText: 'Select Tags',
    height: '250px'
  });
  
  // add an empty value to the select AFTER creating the multioption
  
  $("#test").html(`<option value=""></option>`+$("#test").html())

// comment the next lines out to allow submission
  $("#myForm").on("submit", function(e) {
    console.log($(this).serialize())
    e.preventDefault();
  })

  $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBox", function() {
    var detail = $(this).next();
    detail.show();
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader input", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var hc = $(this).prop("checked");
    $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").find(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input").prop("checked", hc);
    $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").next().UpdateSelect();
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader", function(e) {
    var inp = $(this).find("input");
    var chk = inp.prop("checked");
    inp.prop("checked", !chk);
    $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").find(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input").prop("checked", !chk);
    $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").next().UpdateSelect();
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBoxDetail .cont input", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").next().UpdateSelect();

    var val = ($(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input:checked").length == $(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input").length)
    $(".MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader input").prop("checked", val);
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBoxDetail .cont", function(e) {
    var inp = $(this).find("input");
    var chk = inp.prop("checked");
    inp.prop("checked", !chk);

    var multiCheckBoxDetail = $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail");
    var multiCheckBoxDetailBody = $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody");
    multiCheckBoxDetail.next().UpdateSelect();

    var val = ($(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input:checked").length == $(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input").length)
    $(".MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader input").prop("checked", val);
  });

  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    var container = $(".MultiCheckBoxDetail");
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      container.hide();
    }
  });
});

var defaultMultiCheckBoxOption = {
  width: '220px',
  defaultText: 'Select Below',
  height: '200px'
};

jQuery.fn.extend({
  CreateMultiCheckBox: function(options) {

    var localOption = {};
    localOption.width = (options != null && options.width != null && options.width != undefined) ? options.width : defaultMultiCheckBoxOption.width;
    localOption.defaultText = (options != null && options.defaultText != null && options.defaultText != undefined) ? options.defaultText : defaultMultiCheckBoxOption.defaultText;
    localOption.height = (options != null && options.height != null && options.height != undefined) ? options.height : defaultMultiCheckBoxOption.height;

    this.hide();
    this.attr("multiple", "multiple");
    var divSel = $("<div class='MultiCheckBox'>" + localOption.defaultText + "<span class='k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down'><svg aria-hidden='true' focusable='false' data-prefix='fas' data-icon='sort-down' role='img' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 320 512' class='svg-inline--fa fa-sort-down fa-w-10 fa-2x'><path fill='currentColor' d='M41 288h238c21.4 0 32.1 25.9 17 41L177 448c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0L24 329c-15.1-15.1-4.4-41 17-41z' class=''></path></svg></span></div>").insertBefore(this);
    divSel.css({
      "width": localOption.width
    });

    var detail = $("<div class='MultiCheckBoxDetail'><div class='MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader'><input type='checkbox' class='mulinput' value='-1982' /><div>Select All</div></div><div class='MultiCheckBoxDetailBody'></div></div>").insertAfter(divSel);
    detail.css({
      "width": parseInt(options.width) + 10,
      "max-height": localOption.height
    });
    var multiCheckBoxDetailBody = detail.find(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody");

    this.find("option").each(function() {
      var val = $(this).attr("value");

      if (val == undefined)
        val = '';

      multiCheckBoxDetailBody.append("<div class='cont'><div><input type='checkbox' class='mulinput' value='" + val + "' /></div><div>" + $(this).text() + "</div></div>");
    });

    multiCheckBoxDetailBody.css("max-height", (parseInt($(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").css("max-height")) - 28) + "px");
  },
  UpdateSelect: function() {
    var arr = [];

    this.prev().find(".mulinput:checked").each(function() {
      arr.push($(this).val());
    });

    this.val(arr);
  },
});
```

```css
.MultiCheckBox {
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.MultiCheckBox .k-icon {
  font-size: 15px;
  float: right;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-top: -7px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 14px;
  color: #787878;
}

.MultiCheckBoxDetail {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.MultiCheckBoxDetailBody {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: white;
}

.MultiCheckBoxDetail .cont {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 2px;
}

.MultiCheckBoxDetail .cont:hover {
  background-color: #cfcfcf;
}

.MultiCheckBoxDetailBody>div>div {
  float: left;
}

.MultiCheckBoxDetail>div>div:nth-child(1) {}

.MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 28px;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
}

.MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader>input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 3px;
}

.MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 24px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col">
      <select name="tag[]" class="form-control" id="test">
        <option value="1">Allergy</option>
        <option value="2">Full Day</option>
        <option value="3">Subsidy</option>
        <option value="4">Toddler</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but I am not going to stop submitting the form, If left unchecked I will be able to submit form but without any value of checkbox, currently it is submitting first value

Comment: if left unchecked all the boxes the array should be empty

Comment: Can we hide the checkbox, as in my interface I can see checkbox

Comment: What do you mean? The POINT of your widget is to have checkboxes. What is the ACTUAL effect you are looking for? If you want checkboxes, use checkboxes instead of a select you turn into selectable checkboxes

Comment: No we just added empty option, I want to hide checkbox of that option

Comment: I do not understand- I added AFTER creation so the empty option is not sent and not shown

Comment: I have added the result currently I am getting in question above

Comment: Did you run my snippet? Your example with values 1,2,3 and no empty option works if you add the empty option using script AFTER you run the widget

Comment: Yeah exactly it is same like that

Comment: In your snippet it is fine but I am not getting same result in my application

Comment: See updated snippet - using your values. If you do not get the same, then it is because you are missing showing me something important

Comment: Okay, I have use ```display: none;``` on first div. And this will work, I will write more logic from backend

Answer (score -1):

Use submit handler on the form

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
   var letSubmit = false;
   $('.checkbox').each(function() {
      if($(this).is(':checked') {
         letSubmit = true;
      }
   })
   if(!letSubmit) {
      e.preventDefault();
   }
})
```

Comment: Why not use :checked? See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67856519/295783)

Comment: HTML5 supports required in the element tags, and further more you can check them with on form submit preventing default action then pass it off via ajax or POST.

Comment: @blanknamefornow Required does not work for a bunch of checkboxes if you only want at least one checked

Comment: Thank you for the response but I am not going to stop submitting the form, If left unchecked I will be able to submit form but without any value of checkbox, currently it is submitting first value